# Как передать аргументы в Callback функцию C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Здравствуйте! Весь день пытаюсь разобраться с передачей аргументов в callback функцию.

Допустим, есть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

void test(int a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}

void callbackFunction(void(*cal)(int))
{
    cal(5);
}

int main()
{
    callbackFunction(test);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как сделать, чтобы можно было передавать абсолютно любые аргументы функции, а не только те, которые указаны `void(*cal)(int)`, т.е. можно было вместо `test` передавать любую функцию с любым количеством аргументов любых типов.

Если так будет понятнее, к этой проблеме я пришел, когда хотел сделать таймер, которому нужно указать, какую функцию выполнять чтобы он выполнял бы её в нужное время.

Возможно ли это сделать? Может есть другие пути?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что именно вы хотите. Вот как примерный вариант -

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(int i)
{
    cout << "f(" << i << ")\n";
}

void g(int i, int j)
{
    cout << "g(" << i << "," << j << ")\n";
}

template<class Fn, class... Args>
void callback(Fn&& Fx, Args&&... A)
{
    Fx(A...);
}

int main()
{
    callback(f,5);
    callback(g,1,2);
}
```

Но я не уверен, что это то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

На практике проще всего ограничиться одним аргументом типа `void *`, который вы передаете вместе с адресом функции в `callbackFunction(void(*cal)(void *), void *)`.

Именно его она и должна передать,  вызывая ваш callback.

Т.е. этот аргумент указывает на данные, которые вы подготовите (скорее всего в динамической памяти) перед тем, как зарегистрируете свой callback. В принципе, размер указателя позволяет передавать в нем по крайней мере и unsigned int (если вашему callback этого достаточно для работы).

В качестве примера реализации такой идеи
 можно привести функцию [on_exit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/on_exit.3.html)